# Cursor freezes - keystrokes to release?

Tags: ubuntu, reboot, freeze

Occasionally the mouse cursor will freeze - I have to reboot.

In Ubuntu is there a keystroke combination such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> which would enable me to continue working without  having to reboot?

Answer (score 11):

Just open the Terminal using Ctrl+Alt+T and type the following commands:

`modprobe -r psmouse` for removing it

`modprobe psmouse` for adding it

Comment: worked for me, thanks!

Comment: solves my case where the mouse freezes after the system goes to sleep

Comment: not worked for me. probably my problem is different.

Comment: What exactly is your case?

Comment: Worked for me thank you! I needed `sudo`.

Answer (score 9):

The first thing to try is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. If the GUI is frozen but the keyboard driver is still responding, this will switch to a text console. You can log in to that text console and access your system and try to solve the problem. You can return to the GUI screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (some distributions may use a different number).

If that doesn't work, your computer may still be running, but with the console completely hosed. Then you can still access it over the network, provided you have an SSH server running. Log in from another computer (PC/tablet/phone/…) and try to solve the problem.

If you have no way to access your computer because the console is unavailable and you didn't have an SSH server, you can try killing the whole GUI session with the [magic SysRq key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>: press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, press and release <kbd>SysRq</kbd>, press and hold <kbd>K</kbd>, and finally release <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Depending on your distribution, this may or may not show a new GUI login prompt after a few seconds. If you don't, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a text console, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to switch the keyboard to the text console mode. On a default Ubuntu installation, I think the command to restart the GUI login prompt is `service gdm restart`.

If that doesn't work and you just want to reboot, you can use the magic sysrq keys E, U, B:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to kill all processes but leave them the opportunity to do an emergency save.
2. Wait a couple of seconds, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to allow all file changes to be written to disk.
3. Wait a couple of seconds, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to reboot.

(Do not use or try to remember the popular “REISUB” sequence. The R and S do nothing in this sequence, and the I defeats the purpose of the previous E.)

---

As to what is causing the GUI freeze, the most common culprit is a buggy 3D video driver. 3D video drivers are very complex and video card makers don't provide good support, so the drivers tend to be buggy. Often, the 3D effects are provided by the [Compiz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz) program, and killing the `compiz` process unfreezes the interface. To kill the Compiz process, once you have a command line access, run

```
pkill compiz
```

If you find that you often have freezes due to Compiz, switch to a different desktop environment that doesn't use Compiz. The Ubuntu default (Unity) requires Compiz, but most don't. Try KDE or LXDE (without enabling Compiz of course).

Comment: This key combination (Alt+SysRq+B) restart the computer.

Comment: Thanks for this! Turns out a single process (Archive Manager) had completely frozen the mouse. Killing it resolved the issue immediately! 

Comment: I don't know why but that console after ctrl+f1+alt, is not accepting even the correct password.

Comment: @Vicrobot Maybe your console has a different keyboard layout. Check at the username prompt. The text console and the GUI use completely different keyboard layout mechanisms. Some distributions arrange to set the same default for both, but not all do.

Answer (score 5):

I *was* having the same problem (Ubuntu 20.04); I turned off animations (using TWEAKS) and now everything is fine.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
sudo su

echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

Then press the keystroke <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, this could kill your  X session.

Comment: I tried this & it does work - in as much as it causes the computer to reboot. I was hoping for a way to unfreeze without rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem then i just turned off **SWAP** and now system is running fine.

Answer (score -1):

**update

Please consider pressing the **power button once,**

*insight from the screen blank, please notify the community about the result.*

---

I had this problem

- Clicking the display setting from the desktop,

the mouse just froze

- but the clicks did work.

Solved with **alt + ctrl +f1**

Though no text terminal was opened, it prompted another login screen, there mouse was perfectly functional and after login as well.

(Laptop touchpad)

Comment: This answer merely duplicates part of the [existing answer by Gilles](/a/199749/112566), and doesn't add any value here.  It would be better as a comment there rather than as an additional answer.

Comment: thankyou, probably the solution is not adding value but the additional info is, but its all relative...